# C# Razor Submitted form on Success Refresh Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I have a contact form that is in C# - Razor and built into the Umbraco Scaffold CMS.
Everything almost works .. except after a successful submission - if I refresh the page the web declares I must resubmit the information  - clicking ok then causes the page to attempt a refresh but instead of looking for the page as a page it looks for the action method that was called.
How do I get it to refresh the proper location

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"
    id="btnSubmit"
    type="submit"
    value="submit"
    data-action='CreateMessage'
    style="height: 75px;">
    <h2>Submit</h2>
</button>



function onSubmit(token) {
    document.getElementById("form-outer").submit();
}
```

**EDIT**

```
if (ViewBag.Contact != null)
{
   [mxmissile THIS SHOULD BE A REDIRECT? instead of simple content ..]
    var viewModel = (MyWeb.ContactModel)ViewBag.Contact;

    <div id="form-outer" class="contact-confirmation">
        <div>
            <h2>
                <p>Thank you for your message.</p>
            </h2>
            <p>We will be in touch soon.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
}
else
{
    Html.RenderPartial("/Views/Partials/ContactView.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: Redirect after the initial submission: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: @mxmissile so in my added code - where I have THIS SHOULD BE A REDIRECT - is that what I need to do is on success - or should I do that in my java function for onSubmit?

Comment: No, you will have to handle the redirect in your controller action.